# read data from a csv file using asp net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv

I try to read data from csv file but a i get this error :

```
System.NotSupportedException: Le format du chemin d'accès donné n'est pas pris   en charge.
```

---

and the error source is:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(root + @"C:\Users\user PC\Desktop\données financiere finale\Classeur1.csv");
```

---

this is my code

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var collection1 = db.GetCollection<Devise>("Devise");
        var devises2 = new Devise();

        collection1.InsertOneAsync(devises2);
        var root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

       System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(root + @"C:\Users\user PC\Desktop\données financiere finale\Classeur1.csv");
        string fileLines;

        {
            while ((fileLines = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                string[] elements;
                elements = fileLines.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                for (int x = 0; x < elements.Length; x++)
                {

                    devises2.parité = "EUR/USD";
                    devises2.date_observation = elements[0];
                    devises2.low = float.Parse(elements[3], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                    devises2.high = float.Parse(elements[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                    collection1.InsertOneAsync(devises2);
                }

            }
        }
        return View(devises2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file path is invalid; the current directory is being concatenated with an absolute path (that starts with a drive specifier).

```
var root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Followed by...

```
root + @"C:\Users\user PC\Desktop\données financiere finale\Classeur1.csv");
```

You need to decide whether you want to use a path that is relative to the current directory, or one that you specify using an absolute path.

Comment: thanks this error is resolved but unfortunately the insertion had not worked .

Comment: Like i++ and ++i